# Django 3.1: Access objects in template of ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, templates, modelchoicefield, django-3.1

Using Django 3.1 and I'm struggling with a basic tasks.

I've got a form with a field like this:

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StorageSpace.objects.filter(visible=True), widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

I would like to do this in my view:

```
{% for space in form.available_spaces %}
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input value="{{ space.id }}" data-storage-price={{ space.price }}>{{ space.title }}
        </label>
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I access the attributes of my objects for each choice?
Can't be that difficult, can it? I really need to set the data attribute, otherwise I would just use`{{space}}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
form.available_spaces.field.queryset
```

lets you access the object behind the choice-field. As simple as that.